# Read multiple data from a MATLAB file

Tags: matlab

I am currently trying to read data from a text file written exactly like this:

```
Height = 10
Length = 10
NodeX = 11
NodeY = 11
K = 10
```

I've written a small code like this

```
fileID = fopen('input.dat','r');
[a, b] = fscanf(fileID, '%s %f')
```

And I get the following answer:

```
a =

    72
   101
   105
   103
   104
   116


b =

     1
```

It seems quite obvious I am not mananging to specify the format specification.
I would like to know how to pick a string along with a float multiple times in the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html) for `fscanf` states:

> If `formatSpec` contains a combination of numeric and character
>   specifiers, then `fscanf` converts each character to its numeric
>   equivalent. This conversion occurs even when the format explicitly
>   skips all numeric values (for example, `formatSpec` is `'%*d %s'`).

MATLAB can be annoyingly bad at reading mixed data types. One possible alternative is to read each line and split up your data using a simple regular expression:

```
fileID = fopen('results.txt','r');

mydata = {};
ii = 1;
while ~feof(fileID) % While we're not at the end of the file
    tline = fgetl(fileID); % Get next line
    mydata(ii,:) = regexp(tline, '([a-zA-Z])* = (\d*)', 'tokens');
    ii = ii + 1;
end

fclose(fileID);
```

This returns a `5 x 1` cell array where each cell contains 2 cells (slightly annoying, but you can pull them out) that match your data. In this case, `mydata{1}{1}` is `Height` and `mydata{1}{2}` is `10`.

---

Edit:

And you can flatten your cell array with a [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) call:

`mydata = reshape([mydata{:}], 2, [])';`

Which turns `mydata` in this case into a `5x2` cell array.

Comment: I get the following running regexp
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in main (line 6)
    mydata = reshape([mydata{:}], 2, [])'

Comment: The code provided works for the data file provided. What changes have you made to the data file and/or the code?

Comment: I've managed to get it working. Thank you very much., you have helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `fscanf` function is a low-level I/O function and is often not the best choice for such rather high-level file input. One alternative would be to use the [`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) function, which allows quite advanced format specifications:

```
fileID = fopen('input.dat','r');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s = %d')
```

which creates a 1x2 cell array. The first cell `C{1}` contains another 5x1 cell, where each field contains the name of the field, e.g. `'Height'`. The second cell `C{2}` contains a 5x1 vector containing all integer values from the file.